# How can I update Eclipse's jre location via command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I have a (python) script that unpacks the latest Java JDK into `/opt/java/jdk`, and I would like to update Eclipse's notion of where the JDK, javac, jre, etc are located via that script.

We would like to avoid having every user update their copy of Eclipse individually, both to avoid errors and to avoid having to do it manually.

Comment: Unload it into a jre folder inside Eclipse instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the JDK or JRE your Eclipse instance is using to run itself, you have to modify the `eclipse.ini` file within the main directory of your Eclipse distribution: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

If you want to modify the default JDK/JRE your Eclipse is using for its Java projects, this setting is workspace-specific. Look into your workspace and search for the file `<workspace-dir>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.prefs`:

Here, you can modify or add JREs and JDKs to your workspace's settings. Try modifying the settings via Eclipse to find out all the options. Currently, my preference file looks as follows:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PREF_VM_XML=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8" standalone\="no"?>
<vmSettings defaultVM\="57,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType13,1371044854301">
    <vmType id\="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType">
        <vm id\="1371044854301" name\="jre7" path\="C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7"/>
        <vm id\="1407670365801" javadocURL\="http\://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/" name\="jdk1.7.0_60" path\="C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_60"/>
    </vmType>
</vmSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the eclipse.ini is one way to do it.

Another solution would be to launch eclipse with the -vm argument pointing to /opt/java/jdk/jre/bin/java(?) for instance.

I also know that on windows you can copy a JRE under your eclipse installation directory. You could try creating a link to /opt/java/jdk/jre(?) in yours. It might be working just fine - or not...